# node server running but localhost refusing to connect

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to get the simplest node server interacting with the browser, with this:

```
var http = require('http');


http.createServer(function(req, res){

  res.writeHead( 200, { "content-Type" : 'text/plain' } )
  res.send('Hello world');

}).listen(1337, '192.168.1.2');
```

but localhost won't do it..

```
localhost refused to connect
```

Thats the IPv4 address. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you are on a Mac. First change `192.168.1.2` to `127.0.0.1`, or `0.0.0.0` if you want to be accessible from other computers.

Next browse to http://127.0.0.1:1337/, **not** http://localhost:1337/. For whatever reason `localhost` resolves to `::1` - an IPv6 address on my Mac. For some reason Node immediately disconnects any IPv6 connections on my machine.

Answer (score 4):

Use 0.0.0.0 and it will work both '192.168.1.2' and localhost.

Comment: how? If I interchange `0.0.0.0` with the ip address I already have, nothing changes.

Comment: To work on localhost (that really means localhost:80) you can change your port to 80

Comment: like this? `.listen(80, '192.168.1.2')` ...does not work either. Server won't start now, I get ` throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event`

Comment: It's because you need admin permission to run on 80 (sudo on linux)

Comment: Why not try 3000 or other port

Comment: Sorry you said you already tried 3000, like this .listen(3000, '0.0.0.0') ?

Comment: Instead of using `0.0.0.0` you might also just leave out the second argument to `.listen()`

Comment: server runs with this `.listen('0.0.0.0')`  which port is this though?

Comment: I think this should help [link](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback)

Comment: I have the same issue I ran ipconfig and used my ipaddress and it worked. I really wish i did not have to do this

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res){

  res.writeHead( 200, { "content-Type" : 'text/plain' } )
  res.end('Hello world');

}).listen(1337);
```

1. On node Terminal: node filename.js

   **Leave it open, don't CTRL + C.**
2. Go to  webpage: localhost:1337

It should work. The problem is **not closing** the terminal or **exiting** the execution of the node File.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have just a typo, use `res.end` to send data back and close the connection instead of `res.send`.

Also, you shouldn't have any problem to connect to `localhost`

```
var http = require('http');


http.createServer(function(req, res){

  res.writeHead( 200, { "content-Type" : 'text/plain' } )
  res.end('Hello world');

}).listen(1337, 'localhost');
```

Comment: This worked for me for 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, and localhost.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use these three steps:

1. Type `netstat -aon` on the Command Prompt
2. Find the relative PID number to 127.0.0.1:8080 (or 3000)
3. Run `taskkill /f /pid pidnumber`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect using localhost you have to use "localhost" at listen.

Answer (score -1):

I was having this problem due to closing the CMD.exe window.