# starting a node.js page on localhost - the site can't be reached

Tags: node.js, windows

I'm on Chrome / Windows 7 and trying to make my first node.js steps using this tutorial:

`https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_get_started.asp`

So `myfirst.js` is:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);
```

Going on `http://localhost:8080/` I'm getting the error:

```
This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Firewall is completely off.

Any help?

Comment: Did you remember to give the command `node myfirst.js` in a cmd window? It's possible your program isn't running.  BTW: w3schools?  Friends don't let friends....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node server running but localhost refusing to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283599/node-server-running-but-localhost-refusing-to-connect)

Answer (score 1):

You need to initiate myfirst.js with node, on the CLI by typing the command for it to run

```html
node myfirst.js
```

Answer (score 0):

check your firewall
you must edit in firewall system Node.js as public
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujR8R.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2985.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
console.log(`Server running at: http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});

port=8080
hostname=127.0.0.1  or 192.168.1.x(your ip)

maybe 8080 is use by other software

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but then I installed the pug inside the folder I was working on (basically the folder I named for my website) again and it worked. (idk why did I have to install the package inside the folder as it was installed already outside that folder)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).